# Questions on Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a few questions on the Green's theorem.

It says it needs to be piecewise smooth. It means pieces are differentiable, but how do I check? Can't everything be differentiable? In other words, I can always differentiate everything.

Another question is, it says $P$ and $Q$ have continuous partial derivatives. How do I check that? Do I just take partial derivatives of $P$ and $Q$ and if the partial derivatives of $P$ and $Q$ are continuous, does that mean $P$ and $Q$ have continuous partial derivatives?

Please use positively oriented of integral of $C$ of $\vec{F}\, d\vec{r}$ where $C$ is the boundary of the region enclosed by $y=x$, $y=x^2 - 2x$, and $\vec{F}(x,y) =\langle 3xy, 2x^2\rangle$. Take $3xy$ as $P$ and $2x^2$ as $Q$.

If I take the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, and they both exist, does that show that $P$ and $Q$ have 'continuous' partial derivatives?

Comment: *"I can always differentiate everything"* - how about the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q},\\ 0&\text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$
which is not even continuous?

Comment: Also, [see this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for an explanation of how to write math here.